# How to increase size of an image while saving it in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I have python script which detect `person` and `face` in a frame. First it detects person, then save its image by increasing some image. Then it detects the face in that person image and also save the face image.

As the original saved image of both person and face is very small because I am reducing the size of the frame initially

```
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
```

so that I get good fps and low noise. This is why while saving the image, I have to increase its `width` and `height`. Below is the code I am using and its results:

```
scale_percent = 220  # percent of original size
width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)

dim = (width, height)
resized_img = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Test image I am using is :

[image]

Saved image of face after resize:

[image]

and saved image of person after resize:

[image]

although the person image looks to be fine but face image is very low in quality. Is there any way possible so that we can increase the size (width and height) of the image but still keep it in a good quality. Please help. Thanks

Comment: if you zoom in to the face of the full size image, you'll see the same artifacts. Afaik, there are some interesting newer deep learning zoom approaches, but not sure how well they really work.

Comment: @Micka I think you are right, so this means that we can not resize the image and still retains good pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with INTER_CUBIC or INTER_LACZOS4

```
resized_img = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

I have worked mostly on images and from my experience:
INTER_NEAREST~INTER_AREA < INTER_CUBIC~INTER_LACZOS4~INTER_LINEAR

But still, there will be some amount of pixelation when you do any of these operations, coz you are manipulating the original image data.

Comment: Can you point me to the article which explains all these `INTER_` things please

Comment: For comparision go through https://chadrick-kwag.net/cv2-resize-interpolation-methods/

Comment: For actual implementation go through the documentation of cv2.resize().

Comment: For explanation of INTER_, see https://medium.com/@wenrudong/what-is-opencvs-inter-area-actually-doing-282a626a09b3 and https://chadrick-kwag.net/cv2-resize-interpolation-methods/